How do I use offset within a forEach loop in google apps script
I have a range consisting of a variable number of rows and 4 columns (A,B,C,D). I need to loop through each of the rows and add the number in column D to the number in column C and then clear the contents of column D. I think I can get the adding and the clearing if i can get the correct cells referenced. i was wanting to use a for or foreach loop and then offset from column A to columns C & D but have been unable to get the offset to work.
function AddInventory2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Total Inventory')
  const lrow = sh.getLastRow();
  var Avals = sh.getRange("A1:A"+lrow).getValues();
  var Alast  = lrow - Avals.reverse().findIndex(c=>c[0]!='');
  Avals.forEach(function(row){
   targetCell = Avals.offset(0,3);
   Logger.log(targetCell);
  })
}


I have to apologize for my poor English skills. Unfortunately, I cannot understand I need to loop through each of the rows and add the number in column D to the number in column C and then clear the contents of column D.. Can you provide the sample input and output values you expect? First, I would like to understand your question correctly.

console.log(Avals[0][3])

Avals is a 1 dimensional array so Avals[0][3] is undefined. Were you thinking you want the value in the 3rd column from the current row of the forEach loop?

in Column A&B i have my Item, In Column C i have my Inventory Stock Level and in column D, I type in the qty of new stock that I get. I want the code to then add  the qty of new stock in column D into the qty of the old stock in column C.

Have you considered using on onEdit. As you type a value in column D it will add the value to column C.

Using offset within a for loop:
The code below achieved the desired requirement of offsetting to columns C & D from each of the cells in column A that contain a value.
Note: However, I wouldn't suggest using offset in a loop if you have more complex data, as it can increase the number of calls to the Spreadsheet service, which may slow down execution and cause runtime issues.
Code:
function AddInventory2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Total Inventory');
  const lrow = sh.getLastRow();

  for (let i = 1; i <= lrow; i++) {
    const cellA = sh.getRange(i, 1);
    const cellC = cellA.offset(0, 2);
    const cellD = cellA.offset(0, 3);
    const valueA = cellA.getValue();
    const valueC = cellC.getValue();
    const valueD = cellD.getValue();

    if (valueA !== "") {
      cellD.setValue(valueA);
      cellC.setValue(valueC + valueA);
      cellA.clear();
      cellD.clear();
    }
  }
}

Alternative way for a more complex dataset:
In the future, if you have a large dataset, this approach is much better than the first one. It handles large datasets more efficiently by processing the data in memory and reducing the number of service calls.
function AddInventory2() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Total Inventory');
  const data = sh.getRange(1, 1, sh.getLastRow(), 4).getValues(); // A:D


  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    const valueA = data[i][0];
    const valueC = data[i][2];
    const valueD = data[i][3];

    if (valueA !== "") {
      data[i][3] = valueA;
      data[i][2] = valueC + valueA;
      data[i][0] = "";
      data[i][3] = "";
    }
  }

  sh.getRange(1, 1, data.length, 4).setValues(data);
}

Sample Output:

Reference:
Class Range
for

thank you, i got it to work with your example. i had to tweak it as it did more than what i wanted to. data in columns A & B never change with code.

function AddInventory2() {
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Total Inventory');
const lrow = sh.getLastRow();
for (let i = 1; i <= lrow; i++) {
const cellC = sh.getRange(i+1, 3);
const cellD = sh.getRange(i+1, 4);
const valueC = cellC.getValue();
const valueD = cellD.getValue();
if (valueD !== "") {
  cellC.setValue(valueC + valueD);
  cellD.clearContent();
}

}
}

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvote the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer

Avals.offset(0,3) does not work because Avals is a JavaScript array, not a Range object. Offset only works with Range objects in Google Apps Script.

@EzraMartin I still don't fully understand the meaning of offset from column A to columns C & D. However, if you want to loop each row and add the number in column D to the number in column C, then clear column D, you can try the following function:
var range = sh.getRange(1, 1, lrow, 4);
var values = range.getValues();

for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  var colC = values[i][2];
  var colD = values[i][3];
    
  if (colD !== '' && !isNaN(colC) && !isNaN(colD)) {
    values[i][2] = colC + colD;
    values[i][3] = '';
  }
}

range.setValues(values);


ah ok, I'm fairly new to Apps script. i got most of that code from another site . i thought apps script is java script with some addons. do you have a suggestion on how to offset to columns C & D from each of the cells in column A that contain a value?
